# How to get current item index of ItemsControls in viewmodel?

Tags: wpf

How to get current item index of ItemsControls in viewmodel? 
We want to delete the selected textbox item using ctrl+D in the itemscontrol from the viewmodel

Comment: Use ListBox instead. It has inbuilt selection.

Answer (score 3):

As @metacircle has mentioned, you should use a `ListBox`, which has this functionality built in, instead of your `ItemsControl`. Using a `ListBox`, you have a number of options for accessing the selected item:

[SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[SelectedValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can find code examples on these pages on MSDN and further examples in the [ListBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page.

Answer (score -1):

`ItemsControl` does not have the concept of "current item" nor "current index".

You're looking for a `Selector`-derived control, such as `ListBox`